# How to fight this wp-info.php exploit?

Tags: hacked

Since a few weeks, an exploit has been introduced in my WordPress website and I cannot find a way to remove it definitely. I call it the "wp-info.php exploit" because it puts some `wp-info.php` files somewhere inside the WordPress directories, sometimes deeply buried.

The symptoms of this exploit are not easy to see. The main functionality of the website looks like unaffected, but when I look at the access log I see some strange URLs served by my own site :

- /adult-chat-careers
- /martunis-van-sant-dating
- /astrology-black-singles-personal-ads-free
- ... and a lot a similar ones.

**IMAGE REMOVED**

The page displays my own site structure and menu, but the content is replaced by some spammy text, and scripts are replaced by "img/plugins0.js", "img/plugins1.js", ...

The exploit creates a `wp-info.php` file in `/wp-includes/ID3/` directory (or elsewhere in the WP structure) containing some evil base64-encoded code. For example :

```
<? eval(base64_decode("ICBlc ..... A==")); ?>
```

After decoding, I see that this script makes some `curl` requests to an URL hosted in `doorsshost.com`.

To call this wp-info.php file, the exploit modifies the .htaccess with the following rule :

```
# BEGIN SYSTEM API
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !myclearcode$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ wp-includes/ID3/wp-info.php?$1 [L]
# END SYSTEM API
```

I tried to clean up everything : removing the wp-info.php files and the rule in the .htaccess files, but few hours after my cleaning, the exploit is back, with the `wp-info.php` file placed in a different location.

I am using an old WordPress version (3.6.1) and I will update soon. But I have no guaranty that updating will prevent the exploit to return. Before updating, I would like to understand exactly where is the security breach and how I can fix it.

I post this question here to log the actions I took to find this breach and remove it. Hope this will help others with the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately recovery from hacks is [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, because it cannot be handled in generic form. Someone with expertise (be it hosting security team or third party specialist) _needs_ to be looking at it directly.

Answer (score 3):

In order to limit the impact of the exploit when looking at a solution, I have written a small plugin that checks the `.htaccess` file content every hour and restores the correct file if it has been modified.

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Fight the exploit
 * Author: Fabien Quatravaux
 * Version: 1.0
*/

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'install_fight_exploit' );
function install_fight_exploit(){
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'check_htaccess');
}

function retore_htaccess() {
    $res = copy( dirname(__FILE__) . '/htaccess', get_home_path() . '.htaccess' );
}

add_action( 'check_htaccess', 'check_htaccess' );

function check_htaccess(){
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    $prod = file_get_contents( get_home_path() . '.htaccess' );
    $should_be = file_get_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . '/htaccess' );

    if( $prod != $should_be ) {
        retore_htaccess();
        $num = get_option( 'retore_htaccess_num', 0 );
        $num++;
        add_option( "retore_htaccess_$num", time() );
        update_option( 'retore_htaccess_num', $num );
    }

    return ($prod == $should_be);
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'uninstall_fight_exploit' );
function uninstall_fight_exploit(){
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('check_htaccess');
}
```

As you can see, each time the `.htaccess` file needs to be modified, I log it into the database, along with the time. After one day and a half, I saw that during the first 24 hours after the plugin activation, `.htaccess` files has been modified **each time** the scheduled task has been run. It means that there is some automatic mechanism that put the hack back into the `.htaccess` file !

Then after this first 24 hours period of time, no more modifications has been done, as if the exploit has given up.